# How can I obtain/calculate the memory latency of my GPU without measurement?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu, latency

The `cudaGetDeviceProperties()` API call does not seem to tell us much about the global memory's latency (not even a typical value, or a min/max pair etc).

**Edit:** When I say latency, I actually mean the different latencies for the various cases of having to read data from main device memory. So, if we take [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02308.pdf), it's actually 6 figures:  { TLB L1 hit, TLB L2 hit, TLB miss } x L1 data cache turned { on, off }.

**Q1: Is there a way to obtain these figures, other than to measure them myself?**
Even a rule-of-thumb calculation based on SM version, SM clock and mem clock might do.

I would ask the secondary question, being:
**Q2: If not, is there a utility which does this for you?** 
<sub>(although that  might be off-topic for the site.)</sub>

Comment: But  current voltage can change latency? It should depend on physical properties of that moment. Those may be some another frequency level or relaxed cl timings because of high temperatures(hynix does) at that moment.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Assume no change from the manufacturer's default. Also, multiprocessor clock frequency is a physical setting which could possibly be changed. Finally, differences in timings could allow for a min-max range rather than a fixed value.

Comment: Does [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02308.pdf), in particular figure 14, answer your questions?

Comment: @njuffa: It means I have to edit my question. It also means the usefulness of the figures will be limited.

Comment: Do you need these values at runtime?

Comment: @void_ptr:  I might. I mean, I might schedule different kernels or use different grid configurations based on them. But for now suppose I just want to print these values out.

Comment: The revised question seems to request *hardware* performance data (off topic) or alternatively, ways to determine such hardware performance parameters (too broad, as it would require a detailed description of how to construct appropriate microbenchmarks for each of the parameters desired). The short answer to the question in the title is "no, except by using published results from other people's measurements".

Comment: @einpoklum yes, microbenchmarking papers are sources for basic understanding of the orders of magnitude of the latencies **350 - 700 ns** the GPU SIMD fabric has to wait, before it gets the first byte of data. Cache hierarchies and their respective associativity models are resources, that may help only on such already-brought-in data in case of **re-use**, if not wiped-out already by a LRU-maintenance mechanism (not to pay twice+), so do not rely on improvements unless your computational model is **small-data** ( cache-sizes are rather small ) + high-iteration/convolution **data-reuse** based.

Comment: After a few days, the **citation-based answer about GPU memory-access latencies got deleted too**. Strange habit once citing GPU-facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `cudaDeviceProperties()` is, like the equivalent `cpuid` facility on x86 CPUs, to return relevant microarchitecural parameters. As on CPUs, performance characteristics on GPUs can differ even if the microarchitectural parameters are identical, for example due to different clock frequencies, or due to differing specifications of the attached DRAM, and the way these interact with various buffering and caching mechanisms inside the processor. In general, there is no single "memory latency" number one can assign, nor am I aware of a way to compute possible ranges from known microarchitectural parameters.

On both CPUs and GPU, one therefore has to utilize sophisticated microbenchmarks to determine performance parameters such as DRAM latency. How to construct such microbenchmarks for each desired parameter would be too broad to cover here. Multiple papers have been published that discuss this in detail with regard to NVDIA GPUs. One of the earliest relevant publications is ([online draft](http://www.stuffedcow.net/files/gpuarch-ispass2010.pdf)):

*Wong, Henry, et al. "Demystifying GPU microarchitecture through microbenchmarking." In Proceedings: 2010 IEEE International Symposium on Performance Analysis of Systems & Software (ISPASS), pp. 235-246*

A recent work that includes coverage of the Kepler architecture is ([online draft](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02308.pdf)):

*Xinxin Mei, Xiaowen Chu. "Dissecting GPU Memory Hierarchy through Microbenchmarking." Arxiv manuscript, September 2015, pp. 1-14*

Short of constructing one's own microbenchmarks, one has to rely on published results such as the ones cited above for various implementation-specific performance parameters of specific GPUs.

In many years of optimizing for GPU platforms, I have have not had a need for knowledge of this kind of data, in general the performance metrics of the CUDA profiler(s) should be sufficient to track down specific bottlenecks.

Comment: But the memory clock can differ as well, and we do get that via `cudaDeviceProperties()`, don't we? Also, you don't get to run the profiler on machines your users deploy your software to... unless you write a microbenchmark-based self-tuner.

Comment: @einpoklum: The parameters you are looking for result from complex interaction between the frequency of the GPU core, the frequency of the memory interface, the exact properties of the GPU DRAM (which may have different latencies based on spec and even vendor), various buffering and caching mechanism inside the GPU. There is no single number one could assign to "memory latency", nor do I know of a way to compute the possible ranges from known microarchitectural parameters.

Answer (score -2):

**A1:** A good read on GPU microarchitecture latency landscapes, including figures you are asking about*, are in [**this** http://ufdc.ufl.edu/UFE0043739/00001](http://ufdc.ufl.edu/UFE0043739/00001)

**`Fig. 4.1`** [symbolic multi-SM architecture] and **`Table 4-1.`** PTX instruction category, initiation and execution cycles 
should be born in mind whenever designing costs/benefits-equation before starting to build GPU-kernels.

[**Amdahl's Law** finally **helps quantitatively decide**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3), whether CPU-GPU-CPU pipeline can get your task faster or not.

---

**`A2:`** GPU-instruction code simulators are the way to receive the expected number of `GPU-CLK`s that a particular microarchitecture will have to spend ( at least, as more GPU-kernels might be under the hood concurrently using the hardware resources and thus extending the end-to-end latencies observed in-vivo )

**Numbers matter.**

```
   Category                     GPU
   |                            Hardware
   |                            Unit
   |                            |            Throughput
   |                            |            |               Execution
   |                            |            |               Latency
   |                            |            |               |                  PTX instructions                                                      Note 
   |____________________________|____________|_______________|__________________|_____________________________________________________________________
   Load_shared                  LSU          2               +  30              ld, ldu                                                               Note, .ss = .shared ; .vec and .type determine the size of load. Note also that we omit .cop since no cacheable in Ocelot
   Load_global                  LSU          2               + 600              ld, ldu, prefetch, prefetchu                                          Note, .ss = .global; .vec and .type determine the size of load. Note, Ocelot may not generate prefetch since no caches
   Load_local                   LSU          2               + 600              ld, ldu, prefetch, prefetchu                                          Note, .ss = .local; .vec and .type determine the size of load. Note, Ocelot may not generate prefetch since no caches
   Load_const                   LSU          2               + 600              ld, ldu                                                               Note, .ss = .const; .vec and .type determine the size of load
   Load_param                   LSU          2               +  30              ld, ldu                                                               Note, .ss = .param; .vec and .type determine the size of load
   |                            |                              
   Store_shared                 LSU          2               +  30              st                                                                    Note, .ss = .shared; .vec and .type determine the size of store
   Store_global                 LSU          2               + 600              st                                                                    Note, .ss = .global; .vec and .type determine the size of store
   Store_local                  LSU          2               + 600              st                                                                    Note, .ss = .local; .vec and .type determine the size of store
   Read_modify_write_shared     LSU          2               + 600              atom, red                                                             Note, .space = shared; .type determine the size
   Read_modify_write_global     LSU          2               + 600              atom, red                                                             Note, .space = global; .type determine the size
   |                            |                              
   Texture                      LSU          2               + 600              tex, txq, suld, sust, sured, suq
   |                            |                              
   Integer                      ALU          2               +  24              add, sub, add.cc, addc, sub.cc, subc, mul, mad, mul24, mad24, sad, div, rem, abs, neg, min, max, popc, clz, bfind, brev, bfe, bfi, prmt, mov
   |                            |                                                                                                                     Note, these integer inst. with type = { .u16, .u32, .u64, .s16, .s32, .s64 };
   |                            |                              
   Float_single                 ALU          2               +  24              testp, copysign, add, sub, mul, fma, mad, div, abs, neg, min, max     Note, these Float-single inst. with type = { .f32 };
   Float_double                 ALU          1               +  48              testp, copysign, add, sub, mul, fma, mad, div, abs, neg, min, max     Note, these Float-double inst. with type = { .f64 };
   Special_single               SFU          8               +  48              rcp, sqrt, rsqrt, sin, cos, lg2, ex2                                  Note, these special-single with type = { .f32 };
   Special_double               SFU          8               +  72              rcp, sqrt, rsqrt, sin, cos, lg2, ex2                                  Note, these special-double with type = { .f64 };
   |                                                           
   Logical                      ALU          2               +  24              and, or, xor, not, cnot, shl, shr
   Control                      ALU          2               +  24              bra, call, ret, exit
   |                                                           
   Synchronization              ALU          2               +  24              bar, member, vote
   Compare & Select             ALU          2               +  24              set, setp, selp, slct
   |                                                           
   Conversion                   ALU          2               +  24              Isspacep, cvta, cvt
   Miscellanies                 ALU          2               +  24              brkpt, pmevent, trap
   Video                        ALU          2               +  24              vadd, vsub, vabsdiff, vmin, vmax, vshl, vshr, vmad, vset
```

---

```
+====================| + 11-12 [usec] XFER-LATENCY-up   HostToDevice    ~~~ same as Intel X48 / nForce 790i
|   |||||||||||||||||| + 10-11 [usec] XFER-LATENCY-down DeviceToHost
|   |||||||||||||||||| ~  5.5 GB/sec XFER-BW-up                         ~~~ same as DDR2/DDR3 throughput
|   |||||||||||||||||| ~  5.2 GB/sec XFER-BW-down @8192 KB TEST-LOAD      ( immune to attempts to OverClock PCIe_BUS_CLK 100-105-110-115 [MHz] ) [D:4.9.3]
|   ||||||||||||||||||
|   | PCIe-2.0 ( 4x) | ~ 4 GB/s over  4-Lanes ( PORT #2  )
|   | PCIe-2.0 ( 8x) | ~16 GB/s over  8-Lanes
|   | PCIe-2.0 (16x) | ~32 GB/s over 16-Lanes ( mode 16x )
|   ||||||||||||||||||
+====================|
|                                                                                                                                        PAR -- ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <800> warps ~~ 24000 + 3200 threads ~~ 27200 threads [!!]
|                                                       smREGs________________________________________ penalty +400 ~ +800 [GPU_CLKs] latency ( maskable by 400~800 WARPs ) on <Compile-time>-designed spillover(s) to locMEM__
|                                                                                                              +350 ~ +700 [ns] @1147 MHz FERMI ^^^^^^^^
|                                                                                                                          |                    ^^^^^^^^
|                                                                                                                       +5 [ns] @ 200 MHz FPGA. . . . . . Xilinx/Zync Z7020/FPGA massive-parallel streamline-computing mode ev. PicoBlazer softCPU
|                                                                                                                          |                    ^^^^^^^^
|                                                                                                                   ~  +20 [ns] @1147 MHz FERMI ^^^^^^^^
|                                                             SM-REGISTERs/thread: max  63 for CC-2.x -with only about +22 [GPU_CLKs] latency ( maskable by 22-WARPs ) to hide on [REGISTER DEPENDENCY] when arithmetic result is to be served from previous [INSTR] [G]:10.4, Page-46
|                                                                                  max  63 for CC-3.0 -          about +11 [GPU_CLKs] latency ( maskable by 44-WARPs ) [B]:5.2.3, Page-73
|                                                                                  max 128 for CC-1.x                                    PAR -- ||||||||~~~|
|                                                                                  max 255 for CC-3.5                                    PAR -- ||||||||||||||||||~~~~~~|
|
|                                                       smREGs___BW                                 ANALYZE REAL USE-PATTERNs IN PTX-creation PHASE <<  -Xptxas -v          || nvcc -maxrregcount ( w|w/o spillover(s) )
|                                                                with about 8.0  TB/s BW            [C:Pg.46]
|                                                                           1.3  TB/s BW shaMEM___  4B * 32banks * 15 SMs * half 1.4GHz = 1.3 TB/s only on FERMI
|                                                                           0.1  TB/s BW gloMEM___
|         ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
+========|   DEVICE:3 PERSISTENT                          gloMEM___
|       _|______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
+======|   DEVICE:2 PERSISTENT                          gloMEM___
|     _|______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
+====|   DEVICE:1 PERSISTENT                          gloMEM___
|   _|______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
+==|   DEVICE:0 PERSISTENT                          gloMEM_____________________________________________________________________+440 [GPU_CLKs]_________________________________________________________________________|_GB|
!  |                                                         |\                                                                +                                                                                           |
o  |                                                texMEM___|_\___________________________________texMEM______________________+_______________________________________________________________________________________|_MB|
   |                                                         |\ \                                 |\                           +                                               |\                                          |
   |                                              texL2cache_| \ \                               .| \_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _texL2cache +370 [GPU_CLKs] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | \                                   256_KB|
   |                                                         |  \ \                               |  \                         +                                 |\            ^  \                                        |
   |                                                         |   \ \                              |   \                        +                                 | \           ^   \                                       |
   |                                                         |    \ \                             |    \                       +                                 |  \          ^    \                                      |
   |                                              texL1cache_|     \ \                           .|     \_ _ _ _ _ _texL1cache +260 [GPU_CLKs] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |   \_ _ _ _ _^     \                                 5_KB|
   |                                                         |      \ \                           |      \                     +                         ^\      ^    \        ^\     \                                    |
   |                                     shaMEM + conL3cache_|       \ \                          |       \ _ _ _ _ conL3cache +220 [GPU_CLKs]           ^ \     ^     \       ^ \     \                              32_KB|
   |                                                         |        \ \                         |        \       ^\          +                         ^  \    ^      \      ^  \     \                                  |
   |                                                         |         \ \                        |         \      ^ \         +                         ^   \   ^       \     ^   \     \                                 |
   |                                   ______________________|__________\_\_______________________|__________\_____^__\________+__________________________________________\_________\_____\________________________________|
   |                  +220 [GPU-CLKs]_|           |_ _ _  ___|\          \ \_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ \ _ _ _ _\_ _ _ _+220 [GPU_CLKs] on re-use at some +50 GPU_CLKs _IF_ a FETCH from yet-in-shaL2cache
   | L2-on-re-use-only +80 [GPU-CLKs]_| 64 KB  L2_|_ _ _   __|\\          \ \_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ \ _ _ _ _\_ _ _ + 80 [GPU_CLKs] on re-use from L1-cached (HIT) _IF_ a FETCH from yet-in-shaL1cache
   | L1-on-re-use-only +40 [GPU-CLKs]_|  8 KB  L1_|_ _ _    _|\\\          \_\__________________________________\________\_____+ 40 [GPU_CLKs]_____________________________________________________________________________|
   | L1-on-re-use-only + 8 [GPU-CLKs]_|  2 KB  L1_|__________|\\\\__________\_\__________________________________\________\____+  8 [GPU_CLKs]_________________________________________________________conL1cache      2_KB|
   |     on-chip|smREG +22 [GPU-CLKs]_|           |t[0_______^:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\:________]
   |CC-  MAX    |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[1_______^                  :________]
   |2.x   63    |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[2_______^                  :________] 
   |1.x  128    |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[3_______^                  :________]
   |3.5  255 REGISTERs|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[4_______^                  :________]
   |         per|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[5_______^                  :________]
   |         Thread_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[6_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[7_______^     1stHalf-WARP :________]______________
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ 8_______^:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ 9_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ A_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ B_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ C_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ D_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           |t[ E_______^                  :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|       W0..|t[ F_______^____________WARP__:________]_____________
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|         ..............             
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[0_______^:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\:________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[1_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[2_______^                 :________] 
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[3_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[4_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[5_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[6_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[7_______^    1stHalf-WARP :________]______________
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ 8_______^:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ 9_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ A_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ B_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ C_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ D_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|           ............|t[ E_______^                 :________]
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|       W1..............|t[ F_______^___________WARP__:________]_____________
   |            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|tBlock Wn....................................................|t[ F_______^___________WARP__:________]_____________
   |
   |                   ________________          °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°~~~~~~~~~~°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
   |                  /                \   CC-2.0|||||||||||||||||||||||||| ~masked  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
   |                 /                  \  1.hW  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^| <wait>-s ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
   |                /                    \ 2.hW  |^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^          |^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^
   |_______________/                      \______I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|~~~~~~~~~~I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|I|
   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/ SM:0.warpScheduler    /~~~~~~~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~~~~~~~~~~~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I~I
   |              \          |           //
   |               \         RR-mode    //
   |                \    GREEDY-mode   //
   |                 \________________//
   |                   \______________/
```

---

### GPU-cluster self-reports:

```
* FERMI
* GF100 Server/HPC-GPU PCIe-2.0-16x
*                      GPU_CLK 1.15 GHz [Graphics 575 MHz]
*                      3072 MB GDDR5 773MHz + ECC-correction
* 
*                       448-CUDA-COREs [SMX]-s --> 14 SM * warpSize == 448
*                        48-ROPs
*                        56-TEX-Units, 400 MHz RAMDAC
CUDA API reports .self to operate an API-Driver-version [5000]
                                  on RT-version         [5000]

CUDA API reports .self to operate a limited FIFO [Host] <-|buffer| <-[Device] of a size of 1048576 [B]

CUDA API reports .self to operate a limited HEAP                  for[Device]-side Dynamic __global__ Memory Allocations in a size of 8388608 [B] ( 8 MB if not specified in malloc() call )

CUDA API reports .self to operate cudaCreateStreamWithPriority() QUEUEs
                                                  with <_stream_PRIO_LOW____> == 725871085
                                                  with <_stream_PRIO_HIGH___> == 0


  CUDA Device:0_ has <_compute capability_> == 2.0.
  CUDA Device:0_ has [    Tesla M2050] .name
  CUDA Device:0_ has [             14] .multiProcessorCount         [ Number of multiprocessors on device ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [     2817982464] .totalGlobalMem              [ __global__   memory available on device in Bytes [B] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [          65536] .totalConstMem               [ __constant__ memory available on device in Bytes [B] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [        1147000] .clockRate                   [ GPU_CLK frequency in kilohertz [kHz] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [             32] .warpSize                    [ GPU WARP size in threads ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [        1546000] .memoryClockRate             [ GPU_DDR Peak memory clock frequency in kilohertz [kHz] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [            384] .memoryBusWidth              [ GPU_DDR Global memory bus width in bits [b] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [           1024] .maxThreadsPerBlock          [ MAX Threads per Block ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [          32768] .regsPerBlock                [ MAX number of 32-bit Registers available per Block ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [           1536] .maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor [ MAX resident Threads per multiprocessor ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [         786432] .l2CacheSize
  CUDA Device:0_ has [          49152] .sharedMemPerBlock           [ __shared__   memory available per Block in Bytes [B] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              2] .asyncEngineCount            [ a number of asynchronous engines ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              1] .deviceOverlap               [ if Device can concurrently copy memory and execute a kernel ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              0] .kernelExecTimeoutEnabled    [ if there is a run time limit on kernel exec-s ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              1] .concurrentKernels           [ if Device can possibly execute multiple kernels concurrently ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              1] .canMapHostMemory            [ if can map host memory with cudaHostAlloc / cudaHostGetDevicePointer ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              3] .computeMode                 [ enum { 0: Default | 1: Exclusive<thread> | 2: Prohibited | 3: Exclusive<Process> } ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              1] .ECCEnabled                  [ if has ECC support enabled ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [     2147483647] .memPitch                    [ MAX pitch in bytes allowed by memory copies [B] ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [          65536] .maxSurface1D                [ MAX 1D surface size ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [          32768] .maxSurfaceCubemap           [ MAX Cubemap surface dimensions ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [          65536] .maxTexture1D                [ MAX 1D Texture size ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              0] .pciBusID                    [ PCI bus ID of the device ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              0] .integrated                  [ if GPU-hardware is integrated with Host-side ( ref. Page-Locked Memory XFERs ) ]
  CUDA Device:0_ has [              1] .unifiedAddressing           [ if can use 64-bit process Unified Virtual Address Space in CC-2.0+ ]

  CUDA Device:1_ has <_compute capability_> == 2.0.
  CUDA Device:1_ has [    Tesla M2050] .name
  CUDA Device:1_ has [             14] .multiProcessorCount         [ Number of multiprocessors on device ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [     2817982464] .totalGlobalMem              [ __global__   memory available on device in Bytes [B] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [          65536] .totalConstMem               [ __constant__ memory available on device in Bytes [B] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [        1147000] .clockRate                   [ GPU_CLK frequency in kilohertz [kHz] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [             32] .warpSize                    [ GPU WARP size in threads ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [        1546000] .memoryClockRate             [ GPU_DDR Peak memory clock frequency in kilohertz [kHz] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [            384] .memoryBusWidth              [ GPU_DDR Global memory bus width in bits [b] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [           1024] .maxThreadsPerBlock          [ MAX Threads per Block ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [          32768] .regsPerBlock                [ MAX number of 32-bit Registers available per Block ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [           1536] .maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor [ MAX resident Threads per multiprocessor ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [         786432] .l2CacheSize
  CUDA Device:1_ has [          49152] .sharedMemPerBlock           [ __shared__   memory available per Block in Bytes [B] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              2] .asyncEngineCount            [ a number of asynchronous engines ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              1] .deviceOverlap               [ if Device can concurrently copy memory and execute a kernel ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              0] .kernelExecTimeoutEnabled    [ if there is a run time limit on kernel exec-s ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              1] .concurrentKernels           [ if Device can possibly execute multiple kernels concurrently ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              1] .canMapHostMemory            [ if can map host memory with cudaHostAlloc / cudaHostGetDevicePointer ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              3] .computeMode                 [ enum { 0: Default | 1: Exclusive<thread> | 2: Prohibited | 3: Exclusive<Process> } ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              1] .ECCEnabled                  [ if has ECC support enabled ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [     2147483647] .memPitch                    [ MAX pitch in bytes allowed by memory copies [B] ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [          65536] .maxSurface1D                [ MAX 1D surface size ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [          32768] .maxSurfaceCubemap           [ MAX Cubemap surface dimensions ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [          65536] .maxTexture1D                [ MAX 1D Texture size ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              0] .pciBusID                    [ PCI bus ID of the device ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              0] .integrated                  [ if GPU-hardware is integrated with Host-side ( ref. Page-Locked Memory XFERs ) ]
  CUDA Device:1_ has [              1] .unifiedAddressing           [ if can use 64-bit process Unified Virtual Address Space in CC-2.0+ ]
```

Comment: PTX is a "virtual architecture" and also a compiler intermediate representation. No GPU executes PTX instructions directly, they execute machine code known as SASS, and there is generally only a loose correspondence between PTX and SASS instructions (e.g. note that PTX integer multiplies might be emulated by a SASS instruction sequence, or might map to a hardware instruction). If I interpret the first table correctly, the latency of `600` (cycles?) for global loads seem to be a canonical number based on prior microbenchmark measurements, likely on *older* GPU hardware.

Comment: @njuffa: I think those numbers are the *assumed* execution latencies built into the code analysis tool developed in the PhD project for the purpose of testing different scheduling strategies in gpuOcelot.

Comment: @talonmies -- correct, the PhD also explicitly reports on assumptions & limitations, as njuffa *assumed*.

Comment: @user3666197 FWIW, I did no* downvote. I am not fond of the "wiki" feature of SO and use it exceedingly rarely.

Comment: First of all, I just noticed the answer for some reason - maybe it was because of the downvotes? Anyway, can you explain what these ASCII-art inserts are? And why they contribute to the answer? Also, you may assume for simplicity that only one kernel is running (if that shortens or clarifies your answer).

Comment: @einpoklum Oh yes, sir. Scheme depicts the real hardware "anatomy" of a typical GPU-cluster ( PCI-e hosted devices ). GPU-manufacturers promote fat-numbers, drum about "old" and newer architectures, but the bottom-line is in actual costs of data-*(non)*-locality ( i.e., how expensive it is to move a byte of data from global / constant memory onto a SMX and  there the agony of downvoting and forced deletion ( yes, forced deletion -- censorship? almost ) of answers starts. Architecture depicted is taken from manufacturers own documents. Numbers in [ns] are taken from papers. FERMI is in focus.

Comment: @einpoklum Let me detail the scheme during Sat/Sun, hope you do not mind. Basically it maps, how warp-wide TLP, well, actually a half-wide TLP execution has it's dual role -- **first: benefit time-domain aligned TLP** for half-warp Threads' parallel execution + **second: hide time-domain penalties for memory access** as SMX-caches are small and allow only for some shallow improvements **if-and-only-if** data-scales are small && data-reuse is dominant in the calculation strategy. In all other cases ( any professional design shall validate a-priori ) Amdahl Law shows the limit of GPU-parallelism

Comment: @einpoklum may already know, that SMX can never execute more than one GPU-kernel at any moment in time -- just if one imagines doing so, it would devastate it's ILP and TLP hardware-based half-warp wide parallelism+reduce actual SM-registers (=the fastest storage cells, so valuable for indeed an HPC-grade computing) capacities available for interim data-storage ( thus increase spill-overs to much more time-expensive memory locations, against which your code has no other chance but to wait for read(s) --and, back to the square No.1-- half-warp scheduling can just interleave such group-waitings.